# Error when mocking a repository in unit test of a spring webflux application (using JUnit and Mockito)?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mockito, spring-webflux, junit5

I am yet to find a solution to this.

My Test class:

```
@WebFluxTest(controllers = {PatronController.class})
@Import({PatronService.class}) //to satisfy PatronController dependency.
@ExtendWith({PatronParameterResolver.class})
class PatronFunctionsSpec {
    private Patron patron;
    private Mono<Patron> patronMono;
    private final PatronService patronService = Mockito.mock(PatronService.class);
    @MockBean
    private PatronRepository patronRepository;

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient client;

    @BeforeEach
    void init(Patron injectedPatron) {
        patron = injectedPatron;
        patronMono = Mono.just(patron);
    }

    //Patron Story: patron wants to create an account with us
    @Nested
    @DisplayName("Creating a patron.")
    class CreatingPatron {

        @Test
        @DisplayName("PatronService.create() returns success msg in Response obj after creating patron.")
        void getResponseObjFromServiceCreate() {
            Flux<Patron> patronFlux = Flux.from(patronMono);
            Mockito.when(patronRepository.saveAll(patronMono)).thenReturn(patronFlux);

            PatronService patronService = new PatronService(patronRepository);
            Mono<Response> responseStream = patronService.create(Mono.just(patron));
            Mono<Response> expectedResponseStream = Mono.just(new Response("Welcome, patron. Can't show emojis yet -- sorry."));

            assertEquals(expectedResponseStream, responseStream);
        }
    }
}
```

See my PatronService class with its code:

```
@Service
public class PatronService {

    private final PatronRepository patronRepository;

    public PatronService(PatronRepository patronRepository) {

        this.patronRepository = patronRepository;

    }

    /**
     *
     * persists patron via PatronRepo
     */
    public Mono<Response> create(Mono<Patron> patronMono) {
        patronRepository.saveAll(patronMono).subscribe();
        return Mono.just(new Response("Welcome, patron. Can't find the emojis yet -- sorry."));
    }
}
```

I am testing the PatronService's create(), so need to mock and stub PatronRepository and its function respectively. But the problem is: after running the test case, I get this exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe()" because "patronFlux" is null
at com.budgit.service.PatronService.create(PatronService.java:26)

How can I fix this?

Comment: I would argue that your code inyour service is wrong as well (you shouldn't be calling subscribe but rather have the chain end with your returned value, so you in the end can call subscribe. That being said, there is too little (or at least just fragmented) information in your question to answer this.

Comment: Hello Mr Denium. Thanks for the response. let me implement that.

Comment: I got the return value of 'saveAll(...)' and called subscribe and I got the exact nullException after running

Comment: let me edit the question with more info. Please look at it.

Comment: As stated there is too little informatin in here. How are you testing this (that is not clear from the question, as it contains lines from variousplaces in your test). And you shouldn't be calling `subscribe` anywhere.

Comment: I just editted the question right now.

Comment: Your mockin doesn't match because there is serialization in between and thus it is a different flux instance then you compare with, resulting in the default behavior of mocking to kick in and that is to return `null`.

Comment: I promise to read the Mockito documentation in a near time, however, kindly share more insight. Which argument was serialized? and why would serialization invalidate my stubbing?

Comment: You are invoking a controller, your initial call is converted to JSON from a Mono and back from JSON to a Mono. Hence it is a different instance of Mono theny ou are mocking (although the content is probably the same), hence the matching for the stub doesn't work.

Comment: It worked. Progress! Plus, I understand the reason behind the thrown exception now.

Comment: emm...just before you go, I really hope you check out this other question of mine about validation in a webflux handler method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74331839/fields-validation-not-working-in-a-spring-reactive-controller/74331860#74331860